# Is there a way to trigger an event when mapping out a Component so that it only applies a style to that specific component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a quiz app and I have some components mapped out that when the user clicks an answer it highlights only the one they clicked but so far I've only gotten to work either on hover or just apply it to everybody.

```js
export default function Quiz() {
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(4);
    const [currentAnswer, setCurrentAnswer] = useState("");
    const handleClick = e => {
        setCurrentAnswer(e.target.value);
    };
    const question = quiz.questions[currentQuestion];
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Progress total="3" current="1" />
            <Question question={question.name} />
            <Answers
                question={question}
                currentAnswer={currentAnswer}
                handleClick={handleClick}
            />
            <button className="btn btn-primary">Confirm and Continue</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```js
function Answer(props) {
    let classes = ["answer"];

    if (props.selected) {
        classes.push("selected");
    }

    console.log(props.selected);

    console.log(classes.join(" "));
    return (
        <button
            value={props.letter}
            className={classes.join(" ")}
            onClick={props.handleClick}
        >
            <span className="letter">{props.letter}</span>
            {props.answer}
        </button>
    );
}
```

```js
function Answers(props) {
    return (
        <>
            {props.question.options.map((e, index) => {
                const answer = index + 1;
                return (
                    <>
                        <Answer
                            letter={answer}
                            answer={e.name}
                            selected={answer}
                            handleClick={props.handleClick}
                        />
                    </>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
}
```

This is how my project is setup so far and have been stuck with this problem for a while now

Answer (score 0):

Just do an equality check!

Something along the lines of
`selected={ props.currentAnswer === answer }`

You just need to track whichever answer is selected and set the logic so that your Answer component knows it is selected. You are already doing the check of adding `selected` classname if selected is true.

EDIT: SideNote: Don't forget to add `key` props to your mapped elements! :D Read the documentation for the why.

Comment: The way I did it before it's with ```selected={props.currentAnswer === index + 1} ```but it just worked on hover and didn't stay when it was clicked. I'm gonna try and do it that way. Thanks in advance for the help